# Implicit conversion of super keyword in toString() method to super.toString() not happening

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following two classes as shown below. For the sake of simplicity, 
only toString overridden method is shown .

```
        public class Circle {
        @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Circle";
            }
        }
        public class Cylinder extends Circle {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
     //     return "Cylinder"+this;  // runs without explicitly calling toString() on this keyword
     //     return "Cylinder"+super;  // throws error, asks to delete super token
            return "Cylinder["+super.toString(); // runs without error after adding .toString() with super keyword
            }

}
```

The issue i am having is in my understanding of super keyword . **The toString() of super keyword should be invoked implicitly as is in the case of this keyword** .In fact most of the tutorials and books refer to super keyword as a kind of an object reference to a super class and so it must behave same as this keyword when used with "+" concatenation operator inside toString(). Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Why should it be invoked implicitly? Where is that specified?

Comment: `super` doesn't act like a different object you can call methods on.  It's a special case.

Comment: You probably haven't shown the exact problem or what you need clarification on. What does `Cylinder.toString()` currently return? And what would you expect it to return based on your understanding?

Comment: Added more description as to what i am looking for

Comment: You expect `return "Cylinder"+super;` to do `return "Cylinder["+super.toString();`, similar to `return "Cylinder"+this;` doing `return "Cylinder"+this.toString;`. Nope. `super` is not a reference like `this`.

Comment: I did deduce that . But question is how is it different than this keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `super` keyword is used in two places.

1. The constructor of a subclass.
2. In a overridden method of a subclass.

When used in the constructor, `super()` must be called on the first line. If you are calling another constructor overload, you must call `this()` on the first line of that constructor as well.

A constructor without parameter (i.e. default constructor) does not need to call `super()` if the parent also has a default constructor. This is because the compiler actually does it for you, so it's still there.

When used in an overridden method, you are calling the parent implementation of the method. You cannot call `super()` because that is for parent constructor; you call via `super.foo()`. Unlike `super()`, you must explicitly call this. If you override a method and have empty implementation, then that method does nothing.

Furthermore, `super.foo()` can be used not only in an overridden method. Also, you need not call the same method as the method you are overriding. For example, this is allowed:

```
public void foo() {
    System.out.println(super.toString());
}
```

Although this is allowed, it is more common to call `this.toString()` in this case. This can be used if your class has overridden `toString()` and you do want the original implementation.

Lastly, `super` keyword cannot be used on its own. It is always in a form `super()` or `super.method()`.

Example:

```
public class Base {
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Base";
    }
}

public class Sub extends Base {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(super.toString());
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Sub";
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        sub.foo();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Base
Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The **super** keyword in Java is not an object reference, unlike **this**.

**this** is used as a reference to the calling object.

But, There's no reference-id which can be stored in **super**
**super** is a keyword which is used to RESOLVE the parent CLASS, its methods and data members.

So, you can't print the value of **super** keyword. You can only access methods and members of parent class using **super** keyword.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDfRW.png)

[super](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiFh4.png)

[Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cggP.png)

Comment: add code snippet in your answer rather than images.

Answer (score 2):

As  Louis mentioned in the comment `super` is not a normal object. It is a special case.

According to [java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2)

*The forms using the keyword super are valid only in an instance method, instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. If they appear anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs.*

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java Language Specification §15.11.2 and §15.12.1,

> **Accessing Superclass Members using `super`**
>
> The form `super.Identifier` refers to the field named `Identifier` of the
>   current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of
>   the superclass of the current class.
>
> The form `T.super.Identifier` refers to the field named `Identifier` of
>   the lexically enclosing instance corresponding to `T`, but with that
>   instance viewed as an instance of the superclass of `T`.
>
> ...
>
> **Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to Search** (in a method invocation expression)
>
> If the form is `super.[TypeArguments]Identifier`, then the class to search is the superclass of the class whose declaration contains the method invocation.

It only mentions two forms of the `super` expression - either `super.Identifier` or `T.super.Identifier`. You are using neither of these forms. You are using `super` as if it were `this`, as if it were some kind of variable that you can use on its own. This is not true, `super` behaves very differently from `this`.

If you compare how the spec describes `this`:

> **§15.8.3 `this`**
>
> The keyword `this` may be used only in the following contexts:
>
> - in the body of an instance method or default method (§8.4.7, §9.4.3)
> - in the body of a constructor of a class (§8.8.7)
> - in an instance initializer of a class (§8.6)
> - in the initializer of an instance variable of a class (§8.3.2)
> - to denote a receiver parameter (§8.4.1)

As you can see, this means that `this` can be used on its own. `super` cannot.

In addition, an expression like `"Cylinder"+super` is less readable than `"Cylinder"+suer.toString()`. Don't you think? And by the way, `return "Cylinder"+this;` will probably cause infinite recursion.